# Node.js build json api for heroku

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku, express

I want build API via node.js
it's normal work in local, but fail in cloud.
can you help me to find the bug? thanks

https://infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/host', function(req, res) {
  var sessionId = app.get('sessionId'),
      // generate a fresh token for this client
      token = opentok.generateToken(sessionId, { role: 'moderator' });

  res.json('host.ejs', {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    sessionId: sessionId,
    token: token
  });
```

Logs

```
2014-11-26T03:25:38.289313+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/sample.css" host=infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com request_id=18d8ce80-53a3-487f-94f5-a45f984bad67 fwd="1.171.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=720
2014-11-26T03:25:39.207199+00:00 heroku[router]: http_error="Invalid HTTP status line" at=error code=H17 desc="Poorly formatted HTTP response" method=GET path="/host" host=infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com request_id=a56aaf2e-7d2b-4479-bc01-3efd9542432b fwd="1.171.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=639
2014-11-26T03:30:50+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-11-26T03:30:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-11-26T03:30:55.675999+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy cd3d6fe by kenshin0812@hotmail.com
2014-11-26T03:30:55.675999+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by kenshin0812@hotmail.com
2014-11-26T03:30:55.943650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-11-26T03:30:57.789085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2014-11-26T03:30:58.927452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-11-26T03:30:59.218593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-11-26T03:30:59.079473+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on , server_port 14730
2014-11-26T03:31:00.557311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-11-26T03:31:06.268233+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com request_id=824385d9-4aa9-439d-86a4-e8693d080e6b fwd="1.171.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=2770
2014-11-26T03:31:06.529761+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/sample.css" host=infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com request_id=1f19e9ee-008f-4a33-b66a-bbd7f6b75bea fwd="1.171.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=720
2014-11-26T03:31:08.043604+00:00 heroku[router]: http_error="Invalid HTTP status line" at=error code=H17 desc="Poorly formatted HTTP response" method=GET path="/host" host=infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com request_id=bd19cbbe-bc58-4d4c-8426-d016e29555e1 fwd="1.171.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=503 bytes=635
2014-11-26T03:31:08.041211+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 03:31:08 GMT express deprecated res.json(status, obj): Use res.status(status).json(obj) instead at index.js:43:7
```

as logs, I add state and change to

```
res.status(200).json
```

still not work,
please help, thanks

Comment: I remove view(.ejs) and show json only, it work!
But still dont know how to fix the view's pwd.

Comment: Are you using the right syntax for opentok?  Looking at this link `https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/create-session/node/`it looks like they use the `opentok.createSession()` function instead of the `.generateToken()` function you are using.  If it works locally and not in the cloud can you confirm that you are using the same version of this module both on the cloud and locally?

Comment: No, local is the same issue, and I only need the json back, so I remove the front-end loading, thanks for reply

Comment: What is in index.ejs?

Comment: If you are trying to return only JSON, have you tried removing the `host.ejs` entry so your response will look like `res.json({apiKey:apiKey,sessionId:sessionId,token:token})` to my understanding you should only pass an object to res.json().  If you would like to render `host.ejs` try send that separately with `res.render('host.ejs')`

Answer (score 0):

```
res.json([body])
```

Send a JSON response. This method is identical to res.send() when an object or array is passed.

```
res.json(null)
res.json({ user: 'tobi' })
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' })
```

For a json API service you probably don't need to render anything.

Answer (score 0):

res.json only takes an object, just remove `'host.ejs',`

```
res.json({
   apiKey: apiKey,
   sessionId: sessionId,
   token: token
});
```